# Javascript to prefix the answer with measurement unit

Tags: javascript, html

The below script is meant to calculate the Lean body mass using the body fat percentage and provides the answer in kgs or lbs. 
The program is working fine however the answer is prefixed with pounds regardless of the choice of measurement unit

I know the answer is to modify the below line. Protein refers to the answer and i need to get it prefixed with lbs or kgs depending on what is chosen.
I dont know what function or command can be used to extract the choice.

```
    Get("prot").innerHTML =  protein + ' pounds';}
```

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<form name="bmi" onSubmit="return false;">
  <label>Body Weight</label
  <input name="bodymass" type="text">
  <label>Body Fat<label>
  <input name="fatperc" type="text">
  <select name="measurement">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">Pounds</option>
    <option value="2">Kilograms</option>
  </select>
  <input name="Button1" value="Calculate" onclick="bmicalculate();" type="button">
  <input type=reset value=Reset>
  <label>Results<label>
  <div id="prot"></div>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function bmicalculate() {
    var bodymass = "";
    var measurement = "";
    var fatperc = "";
    var bodymass1 = "";
    var bodymass2 = "";
    var pounds = "";
    if (document.bmi.bodymass.value=="") {
      alert('Oops, please enter your weight.');
      return false;
    }
    if (document.bmi.bodymass.value < 0) {
      alert('Oops, your weight must be a positive value.');
      return false;
    }
    bodymass = parseFloat(document.bmi.bodymass.value);
    measurement = document.bmi.measurement.selectedIndex;
    measurement = document.bmi.measurement.options[measurement].value;

    if (measurement == "2") {
      pounds = (bodymass * 2.2);
    } else {
      pounds = bodymass;
    }

    fatperc=document.bmi.fatperc.value;

    if (fatperc == "") {
      alert('Please estimate your bodyfat percentage.');
      return false;
    }
    if (fatperc > 100) {
      alert('Oops, percentages cannot be over 100%.');
      return false;
    }
    if (fatperc < 0) {
      alert('Oops, percentages must be a positive number.');
      return false;
    }
    bodymass1 = Math.round(pounds-(pounds/100*fatperc));
    bodymass2 = Math.round(bodymass1/2.2);
    if (measurement == "2") {
      protein = Math.round(bodymass2 * 1);
    } else {
      protein = Math.round(bodymass1 * 1);
    }
    Get("prot").innerHTML = protein + ' pounds';
  }

  function Get(oName,oFrame,oDoc) {
    if (!oDoc) {
      if (oFrame) {
        oDoc = oFrame.document;
      } else
        oDoc = window.document;
      }
    }
    if (oDoc[oName]) {
      return oDoc[oName];
    }
    if (oDoc.all && oDoc.all[oName]) {
      return oDoc.all[oName];
    }
    if (oDoc.getElementById && oDoc.getElementById(oName)) {
      return oDoc.getElementById(oName);
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < oDoc.forms.length; x++) {
      if (oDoc.forms[x][oName]) {
        return oDoc.forms[x][oName];
      }
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < oDoc.anchors.length; x++) {
      if (oDoc.anchors[x].name == oName) {
        return oDoc.anchors[x];
      }
    }
    for (var x = 0; document.layers && x < oDoc.layers.length; x++) {
      var theOb = Get( oName, null, oDoc.layers[x].document );
      if (theOb) {
        return theOb;
      }
    }
    if (!oFrame && window[oName]) {
      return window[oName];
    }
    if (oFrame && oFrame[oName]) {
      return oFrame[oName];
    }
    for (var x = 0; oFrame && oFrame.frames && x < oFrame.frames.length; x++) {
      var theOb = Get( oName, oFrame.frames[x], oFrame.frames[x].document );
      if (theOb) {
        return theOb;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change below line in code-

```
Get("prot").innerHTML =  protein + document.bmi.measurement.options[measurement].text
```

Comment: thanks this works! i also need a space between the result and the prefix eg. 85 kgs. The result currently is ' 85kgs '

Comment: figured it out thanks    *** Get("prot").innerHTML =  protein +' '+ document.bmi.measurement.options[measurement].text    ***

Answer (score 2):

Get the selected `measurement` text

```
   var measurementText = document.bmi.measurement.options[measurement].text;
```

Then change

```
   Get("prot").innerHTML =  protein + ' pounds';
```

to

```
    Get("prot").innerHTML =  protein + ' ' + measurementText;
```

An example which just alerts the selected option's text on a select change

```js
function optionText() {
  var select = document.form.select;
  var selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;
  var text = select.options[selectedIndex].text;
  
  alert(text);
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <select name="select" onchange="optionText()">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```